# How to select rows by id from a string of multiple ids

Tags: mysql

every rows having multiple ids separated by comma. i want to select rows by id.

Database is like this:

```
R.No | User_Ids
-----|---------
1    | 38,323,45
-----|----------
2    | 382,535,338
-----|------------
3    | 32,38
-----|----------
4    |238,388,2394
```

if selected id is **38** then i need result as below:

```
R.No | User_Ids
-----|---------
1    | 38,323,45
-----|----------
3    | 32,38
```

i have used this query.

```
$sql="select User_Ids from table_name where User_Ids RLIKE '[[:<:]]".$Id."[[:>:]]'";
```

It is giving error as **Illegal argument to a regular expression.**

Comment: now you know why placing link keys in a comma delimited list is madness

Comment: If its not too late, check out a database design for beginners course, then create a link table between this table and the user table

Comment: (The mentioned duplicate explains how this _can_ be done, but that changes rather little about the fact that this should probably rather be properly normalized, if at all still possible at this point.)

Answer (score 0):

You can get desired result using [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE find_in_set(38, `Ids`);
```

[Here you can test it](https://phpize.online/?phpses=cc90024fac85a46bb9e922cfe20c9145&sqlses=7b7f8199f1a825baf5ab384b5cb16961&php_version=php5&sql_version=mysql80)